# Cannot obtain alignment summary after running Bowtie2

Tags: rna-seq, sequence-alignment, bowtie2

I am aligning my Small RNA Seq data with Bowtie 2. Although the alignment performs well, the only information I obtain after finishing running the alignment is the following:

```
## Time loading reference: 00:00:00
## Time loading forward index: 00:00:00
## Time loading mirror index: 00:00:00
## Multiseed full-index search: 00:00:00
## Time searching: 00:00:00
## Overall time: 00:00:00
## Time loading reference: 00:00:00
## Time loading forward index: 00:00:00
## Time loading mirror index: 00:00:00
## Multiseed full-index search: 00:00:01
## Time searching: 00:00:01
## Overall time: 00:00:01
## Time loading reference: 00:00:00
## Time loading forward index: 00:00:00
## Time loading mirror index: 00:00:00
## Multiseed full-index search: 00:00:00
## Time searching: 00:00:00
## Overall time: 00:00:00
## Time loading reference: 00:00:00
## Time loading forward index: 00:00:00
## Time loading mirror index: 00:00:00
## Multiseed full-index search: 00:00:00
## Time searching: 00:00:00
## Overall time: 00:00:00
## Time loading reference: 00:00:00
## Time loading forward index: 00:00:00
## Time loading mirror index: 00:00:00
## Multiseed full-index search: 00:00:00
## Time searching: 00:00:00
## Overall time: 00:00:00
## Time loading reference: 00:00:00
## Time loading forward index: 00:00:00
## Time loading mirror index: 00:00:00
## Multiseed full-index search: 00:00:00
## Time searching: 00:00:00
## Overall time: 00:00:00
```

This is my command line to build the index:
bowtie2-build -o 3 -t 5 Nuevofastaorina human_mirs

And this is my command line to do the alignment:

```
bowtie2 -x human_mirs -U 1.lane.clean.gz -N 1 --norc --no-unal --no-head --ignore-quals –-quiet > sr1prueba.sam
```

Does anyone know how to obtain an alignment summary instead of the above information? What I mean by alignment summary is the following:

```
20000 reads; of these:
  20000 (100.00%) were unpaired; of these:
    1247 (6.24%) aligned 0 times
    18739 (93.69%) aligned exactly 1 time
    14 (0.07%) aligned >1 times
93.77% overall alignment rate
```

Comment: Please show the first few lines of your fastq input data (i.e. lane.clean.gz). This should help to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Remove the `--quiet` option, and capture STDERR as well as STDOUT:

```
bowtie2 -x human_mirs -U 1.lane.clean.gz -N 1 --norc --no-unal --no-head --ignore-quals 1>sr1prueba.sam 2>sr1prueba.summary.log
```

**See also:**

[`bowtie2` manual: alignment summary](https://bowtie-bio.sourceforge.net/bowtie2/manual.shtml#alignment-summary)

Answer (score 2):

Get [samtools](http://www.htslib.org/).

Then run:

```
samtools stats file.bam
```

and/or

```
samtools flagstat file.bam
```

For example outputs see [here](https://www.biostars.org/p/412621/).